# Python list iteration/modification issue even when copying list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have reviewed a lot of other posts and I do understand that you don't want to modify a list as you iterate over it.  I am still getting the dreaded 'list.remove(x): x not in list' so clearly I am still trying to modify something when I shouldn't, just can't figure out where.

First here is the portion of the function that calls the function doing the work and returning a list:

```
for inn in range(1,7):
    for pos in lstPositions:
    weight = 10
    posAssigned = 0
        while (posAssigned == 0):
            lstPlayers = getWeights(weight,pos,inn)
```

As you can see I want to get a list of players back as the return value.  Now here is the function `getWeights`.  As you can see in the second section I am first copying `lstPlayersFunc` to `lstPlayersTmp` and iterating over `lstPlayersTmp`, modifying `lstPlayersFunc`.  The traceback, which I have pasted below shows the issue when I am trying to remove an element from `lstPlayersFunc`.

```
def getWeights(weight,pos,inn):
    lstPlayersFunc = []
    for player in positions:
        if positions[player][pos] == weight:
            lstPlayersFunc.append(player)

lstPlayersTmp = lstPlayersFunc[:]
for player in lstPlayersTmp:
    maxBench = 6 - positions[player]['MaxInn']
    for pos in lstPositions:
        if lineup[str(inn)][pos] == player:
            lstPlayersFunc.remove(player)
        elif positions[player]['MaxInn'] <= cntPos[player]['total']:
            lstPlayersFunc.remove(player)
        elif positions[player]['MaxPitch'] <= cntPos[player]['P']:
            lstPlayersFunc.remove(player)
        elif positions[player]['MaxCatch'] <= cntPos[player]['C']:
            lstPlayersFunc.remove(player)
        elif maxBench <= cntPos[player]['B']:
            lstPlayersFunc.remove(player)

return lstPlayersFunc
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./lineups4.py", line 126, in <module>
posAssign()
File "./lineups4.py", line 93, in posAssign
lstPlayers = getWeights(weight,pos,inn)
File "./lineups4.py", line 76, in getWeights
lstPlayersFunc.remove(player)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Comment: The indentation in your first block is off (the inner `for` has no body, while the innermost `while` is indented an extra level with no block introducing it)); can you correct it?

Comment: are you sure you're not just trying to remove the same player twice? you've got the `for pos in lstPositions` nested loop that, if any of the conditions is true, will try to remove the same player in each iteration...

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide enough code to be sure, but I'm guessing you're removing the same `player` multiple times. Your loop is structured as:

```
for player in lstPlayersTmp:
    maxBench = 6 - positions[player]['MaxInn']
    for pos in lstPositions:
        # A number of tests any one of which passing removes the player
```

Problem is, the inner `for pos in lstPositions:` loop doesn't terminate if you hit on one of the tests and `remove` a `player`. At a guess, two different `pos` values lead to a passing test, and the second time around, you try to `remove` a `player` that's already gone.

Try adding a `break` after each of the `remove` calls in that loop. After all, once the player is `remove`-ed, you don't care about them anymore, so you can stop checking new `pos` and move on to the next `player`.

Comment: That sounds right -- I will give it a try.  Thanks.

Comment: Yep - that was it.  Thanks, that was driving me nuts!